# Can't run a code that includes "./" in google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm new to colab, and I can't seem to find how to run this code in colab, the original code is:

```
cd megatools-1.10.3/ ./configure make sudo make install
```

and all I have so far is:

```
%cd megatools-1.10.3/ ./configure make sudo make install
```

Can you please help me? Thanks.

Comment: What error did you encounter? Can you share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the error observed?

Comment: @BobSmith I get the regular command not found error, I want to know how to execute such commands:
 ./.megarc
~/.megarc
$ megatools
in google colab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. It's:

%cd megatools-1.10.3

!./configure make sudo make install

Answer (score 0):

You may need to put them on multiple lines, like this.

```
%cd megatools-1.10.3/ 
! ./configure 
! make
! make install
```